# Riemann-Hilbert approach to Selberg integral

Tags: mp.mathematical-physics, random-matrices, orthogonal-polynomials

I am interested in matrix integrals, and I have seen many mentions to a certain Riemann-Hilbert approach that indicate that this is a very powerful tool to can be used in this area, when coupled with the theory of orthogonal polynomials. I would like to understand it, but the sources I found were hard to follow.

It would be helpful if I could see it in action in a simple case, so I suggest what follows. Consider the matrix integral
$$ f(a,N)=\int_{0}^\infty e^{-a\sum_{m=1}^\infty \frac{1}{m}{\rm Tr}(X^m)}|\Delta(X)|^2dX,$$
where $a>0$, $\Delta(X)$ is the Vandermonde and $X$ is diagonal of dimension $N$. I would like to know if this kind of integral is amenable to the R-H approach (with a non-polynomial potential).

The series in the exponent is only finite if $0< X< 1$, in which case it gives $-{\rm Tr}\log(1-X)$ so using that $e^{-\infty}=0$ (I am not sure how rigorous this can be made):
$$f(a,N)=\int_{0}^1 \det(1-X)^a|\Delta(X)|^2dX,$$
which is a particular case of the Selberg integral and there is an explicit solution to it, which is
$$\prod_{j=0}^{N-1}\frac{\Gamma(a+j+1)j!(j+1)!}{\Gamma(a+N+j+1)}.$$

My question is: how can the R-H approach be applied to the first integral in order to produce the Selberg result?

Comment: ``in which case it gives $-\log(\det(I-X))$ so ...''

Comment: Please give more details and/or references for the question. For instance: $X$ of shape $N$ in the "interval" from zero to infinity means $X$ is in which ensamble more exactly? From what can be seen *where* the integral defining $f(a,N)$ is amenable to the R-H approach? How to get the second formula for $f(a,N)$ (alternatively)? How can the R-H approach be used to produce the Selberg result in small dimensions, e.g. $N=1$ (and $N=2$)? And why is the "potential" $$V(M) = \sum_{k\ge 1} \frac 1k M^k$$of interest?

Comment: @dan_fulea $X$ is diagonal, I have included that. The question is in fact whether the first integral is amenable to R-H, so I removed the "have seen" comment as it was confusing. The second formula for the integral is due to Selberg, this is a classical result. I have no idea how to use R-H in small dimensions (in fact I suspect it is designed to be used in large $N$ situations but I am not sure).

Comment: @dan_fulea that potential is of interest as a test ground precisely because it leads to a Selberg integral, which is exactly solvable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let me formulate the problem in a slightly more general way: We seek to evaluate the large-$N$ limit of the matrix integral
$$\int e^{-\beta\,{\rm Tr}\,V(X)}|\Delta(X)|^\beta dX\equiv e^{-\beta N^2 F},$$
integrated over $N\times N$ Hermitian matrices $X$. In the OP the index $\beta=2$ and $V(X)=(a/2)\sum_m m^{-1}X^m$, which creates convergence problems, here I assume $V(\lambda)$ is a well defined function of the eigenvalues $\lambda$ of $X$. My goal here is to reduce the calculation of the matrix integral in the large-$N$ limit to the solution of a nonlinear integral equation which can be solved by the Riemann-Hilbert technique.

<sub>Note for the OP: Selberg integrals are exact finite-$N$ results. The Riemann-Hilbert technique evaluates these integrals in the large-$N$ limit, by the method of stationary phase (or steepest descent). There is therefore no direct connection between the two techniques.</sub>

Because of the invariance under unitary transformations the integral over the matrix elements can be reduced to an integral over the eigenvalues,
$$e^{-\beta N^2 F}=\int_{-\infty}^\infty d\lambda_1\cdots \int_{-\infty}^\infty d\lambda_N \,e^{-\beta U(\lambda_1,\ldots\lambda_N)},$$
$$U(\lambda_1,\ldots\lambda_N)=\sum_{i=1}^N V(\lambda_i)-\sum_{i<j}\ln|\lambda_i-\lambda_j|,$$
where I have used that $\Delta(X)=\prod_{i<j}|\lambda_i-\lambda_j|$.

In the large-$N$ limit the integral can be evaluated by the method of stationary phase:
$$F=\lim_{N\rightarrow\infty} N^{-2} U(\lambda^\ast_1,\ldots\lambda^\ast_N),$$
where the $\lambda^*_i$'s satisfy the stationarity equations
$$\frac{\partial U}{\partial\lambda_i}=0\Rightarrow V'(\lambda_i)=\sum_{j\neq i}\frac{1}{\lambda_i-\lambda_j},\;\;i=1,2,\ldots N.$$
Intuitively, this equation expresses a condition of mechanical equilibrium of $N$ particles on a line, coordinates $\lambda_i$, moving in a potential $V(\lambda)$ and repelling each other pairwise with a logarithmic interaction.

The next step is replace the sum over the discrete index $i$ by an integral over the continuous variable $x$. For that purpose we define a function $\lambda(x)$ by $\lambda_i=N^{1/2}\lambda(i/N)$ and we define the rescaled potential
$$V_\infty(\lambda)=\lim_{N\rightarrow\infty}N^{-1}V(N^{1/2}\lambda),$$
assuming that this limit exists. Upon replacement of $\sum_i f(\lambda_i)\mapsto N\int dx\, f(N^{1/2}\lambda(x))$ we thus arrive at
$$F=\int_{-\infty}^\infty V_\infty(\lambda(x))\,dx-\tfrac{1}{2}\int_{-\infty}^\infty dx\int_{-\infty}^\infty dy\,[\ln |\lambda(x)-\lambda(y)|+\tfrac{1}{2}\ln N].$$

The unknown function $\lambda(x)$ is determined by the stationarity equation
$$\frac{d}{d\lambda}V_\infty(\lambda(x))=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}dy\frac{1}{\lambda(x)-\lambda(y)}.$$
Defining the density function $\rho(\lambda)=(d\lambda/dx)^{-1}$, with support $(a,b)$, the stationarity equation can be rewritten as
$$V'_\infty(\lambda)=\int_{a}^{b}d\mu\frac{\rho(\mu)}{\lambda-\mu},\;\;\lambda\in(a,b).$$
The Cauchy principal value of the integral is intended.

This integral equation can now be solved by the Rieman-Hilbert technique. For a worked out example for $V(\lambda)=\tfrac{1}{2}\lambda^2+(g/N)\lambda^4$ see the paper [Planar diagrams](http://www.lpthe.jussieu.fr/~zuber/MesPapiers/bipz_CMP78.pdf) by Brézin, Itzykson, Parisi, and Zuber.

---

For the quadratic case, $V(\lambda)=\tfrac{1}{2}\lambda^2=V_\infty(\lambda)$, the solution of the integral equation is
$$\rho(\lambda)=\frac{1}{\pi}\sqrt{2-\lambda^2},\;\;\lambda\in(-\sqrt 2,\sqrt 2),$$
which gives
$$F=\int_{-\sqrt 2}^{\sqrt 2}\tfrac{1}{2}\lambda^2\rho(\lambda)\,d\lambda-\tfrac{1}{2}\int_{-\sqrt{2}}^{\sqrt{2}}d\lambda\int_{-\sqrt 2}^{\sqrt 2} d\mu\,\rho(\lambda)\rho(\mu)[\ln|\lambda-\mu|+\tfrac{1}{2}\ln N]$$
$$\qquad=\frac{3+\ln 4}{8}-\frac{1}{4}\ln N.$$
This can then be compared with the corresponding Selberg integral, which reads
$$S_N=\int e^{-\tfrac{1}{2}\beta\,{\rm Tr}\,X^2}|\Delta(X)|^\beta dX=(2\pi)^{N/2}\beta^{-N/2-\beta N(N-1)/4}\prod_{j=1}^N\frac{\Gamma(1+\beta j/2)}{\Gamma(1+\beta/2)}.$$
So I should check that
$$\lim_{N\rightarrow\infty}N^{-2}\ln S_N=-\frac{3+\ln 4 }{8}\beta+\frac{1}{4}\beta\ln N.\;\;(1)$$
I find
$$\lim_{N\rightarrow\infty}N^{-2}\ln S_N=-\frac{\beta}{4}\ln \beta+\lim_{N\rightarrow\infty}N^{-2}\sum_{j=1}^N\ln\Gamma(1+\beta j/2)$$
$$=-\frac{\beta}{4}\ln \beta+\lim_{N\rightarrow\infty}N^{-2}\int_1^N \tfrac{1}{2} j \bigl( \beta \ln \beta j- \beta-\beta \ln 2\bigr)\,dj$$
$$=-\frac{3+\ln 4}{8}\beta+\frac{1}{4}\beta\ln N.\;\;(2)$$
It agrees.

Comment: If you consider $0<X<1$ from the start, you can take $V$ to be the well defined function $a\log(1-X)$. Although there is no direct connection between the two techniques, the question is whether R-H is capable of reproducing the Selberg result, at least to leading orders.

Comment: I have added an explicit comparison between the RH asymptotic result and the large-N limit of the Selberg integral for the case of a quadratic $V$ (where I know how to solve the RH equation). There is probably still an error in my calculation, and I'm unable to carry out the large-N limit of the product of Gamma functions, so I have compared them numerically.

Comment: Ok, I still wonder if the case $V=\log(1-X)$ can be done, but thank you for your answer.

Comment: I fixed the error in the coefficient, the asymptotic result now agrees with the Selberg expression in the large-$N$ limit.

Comment: concerning the $V=-a\log(1-X)$ potential: to be able to use the RH approach in the large-$N$ limit the coefficient $a=\alpha N$ must increase linearly with $N$; the calculation then proceeds along the same lines as for the quadratic potential, it's just a more complicated RH equation that one has to solve, in particular the support of the solution will be an $\alpha$-dependent sub-interval $(0,c)$ of $(0,1)$, with a $1/\sqrt{c-x}$ singularity at the upper limit.